# PHP search results pagination without running the query multiple times

Tags: php, search, mysqli, pagination

I've searched the web on how to do a search results pagination in PHP and I came into posts like this: http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm

Whenever a different page of the results is asked, the query is executed again, and the thing that changes is the 'limit'.

But, what if my database is very large and I want to avoid searching through it each time (using something like `select *  from articles where HTML like '%dummy%' limit x, y`) ?

As far as I understand the database will search itself each time and it will return different results based on `x` and `y`.

Comment: Save the results in a `$_SESSION`?

Comment: No, that doenst fix his problem :) the problem is in the double selecting, not saving the actual results (which also wouldn't require a session)

Answer (score 1):

You simply cant do this (efficiently) with one query, you will always need one to select the result, and one to get the number of items in total.

There is a way to improve it though, you only need the number of rows in the 2nd query:

```
// Query one, to select the actual content:
Select * from articles where HTML like '%dummy%' LIMIT $start,$num_items
// Query two, select an index column, preferable a small int column:
Select id from articles where HTML like '%dummy%'
```

I have been working on a webshop, not the largest database, but 3500 products, with 1 to N images, 1 to N classes and some other very large tables (in amounts), and that works perfectly :)

---

You can do it in 1 query if you want. Just select the whole bunch and make PHP skip lines untill reach `start` and break the loop when you have your `limit` reached. However, that takes a whole lot more time (and resources!) than running the query again. If you want to improve speed, make sure you have the `html` column indexed, that will save alot of time. 
Rememer, this (mysql-)database is made for searching fast, php isnt

---

If you have a huge dataset, you might want to change tactics all the way. You could count the number of rows and make a new table you could call something like `table_info` and add a row called `number_of_rows_in_TABLENAME` and update that with an new insert, and subtract one of you delete a line, but this method gets sloppy really fast of you forget something

Comment: *sigh*, If you downvote, explain why so I can improve the answer.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I really don't understand your thought here. The only things that I want in order to display my page is the total results matching the search criteria, the results themselves and the items I want to have per page. I don't see why I should execute 2 queries and also I don't see how this answers my question: How to avoid running the query again (which will search the database again) in every page that the user selects?

Comment: So, if I got it right, by running query No2 I have all the ids that much my criteria, so when the page changes I will search through the table containing all the matching ids and extract the ones matching the current page? And where do I save this table so as to have access to it when the page changes? Also, why not to just run query No2 and then extract from the database the ids (I don't understand why query No1 is even needed. To display the items at the current (first) search results page?)

Comment: Q1 is to select the items on your page, this is not needed for pagination. To continue the webshop example, thats where you select the information of the products. Q2 is the one needed for the total amount of pages. Q1 selects the things you want to show, Q2 selects the number of items.

Comment: You can, if you must, save the number of lines in session to the next page doesnt require that query. Hoever, if you table changes, it no longer is correct. I dont think you need to worry allot about Q2, with proper indexes its fast enough (unless you have weirdly much content)

Comment: That's my though on my previous
 comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZbHqVek.png but it requires cross saving the matching IDs. I will try your suggestion and I will see how it matches my needs. Thanks.

Comment: I wish upvotes were questioned the same way as downvotes. Sometimes I *really* wish to know what one may think for a reason.

Comment: @Martijn I just understood your thought and it doesn't answer my question at all. You do exactly what I said that I want to avoid, that's why I became confused. Executing Query No1 every time is the thing that I want to avoid.

Comment: Q1 is the one that selects content for the user. If you dont need that, drop it. For pagination you only need Q2, as I mentioned earlier :) My answer is indeed exactly what you want to avoid, but I changed the `query performed twice` to a 2nd query which select alot less

Comment: Nope, of course I need to show part of each article's content to the user, so I need Q1. And to create this: http://i.imgur.com/SryX2Ks.png of course you only need Q2... But you get my point... If I can somehow achieve what I painted at the previous image...

Comment: You mean two different pages in 1 query? That would be silly, why would there be a limit in the first place :P One thing you *might*  do is remember the ID of the last item of the result and add in the 2nd page `WHERE id>$lastId AND HTML like '%search%'`. The id selecter would be a fast one